# How do I get a POST response using React Native WebView?

Tags: react-native, webview

I am trying to extract the POST response from the WebView in React Native but onMessage doesn't seem to solve this. The code below works to navigate a website using the WebView but it does not `console.log` anything. Is there anything I'm missing or misreading in the documentation for WebView?

```
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

return (

    <WebView
      source={{
        uri: `https://www.example.com/`
      }}
      onMessage={(event)=>console.log(event)}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onMessage` function is used for Web and communication.

You can use `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage`

**Example**

```js
const runFirst = `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("this is message from web");`;

<WebView
  source={{
    uri:
     'https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview',
    }}
    injectedJavaScript={runFirst}
    onMessage={(event)=> console.log( "On Message", event.nativeEvent.data )}
 />
```

Comment: Thanks for offering the help, maybe I'm missing something but this just logs "this message from web" as the data. Instead, I'm seeking the post response that is sent when someone goes to the website. For example, if I go to the url in my browser: `https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview` I see a GET request to ```https://github.com/users/mclimb/feature_preview/indicator_check.json``` and a short json response. It's that json response I'm seeking.  Again, maybe I'm missing something in your answer :)

Comment: @mpc75 When calling API from web to GET, send the response value to webview to `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage`.

Comment: would you mind pointing me to some docs that explain what you mean? I'm not following well.

Comment: @mpc75 As you said, there will be an Api that runs when a page is moved on the web. It has a response value. You can send the response. If the homepage is not made by you, please call directly to check the data.